# Way to Shrink Alaska and Hawaii for "Stereotypical View"

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, print-composer, scale

Is there anyway to shrink Alaska and Hawaii to create a map that looks like the stereotypical map with AK in the corner, etc.? I thought about trying to isolate AK and HI in their own layers and then move those independently in the Print Composer but thought I'd see if there was an easier way.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to deliberately distort your state polygons by shrinking and moving Alaska and Hawaii so that they appear in a location that is conducive to a print layout, completely destroying their geographic integrity?

Comment: Sometimes you can use an "inset map." In ArcGIS, you could have separate data frames and then place each data frame on a layout.

Comment: @nmpeterson Yes sadly (coming from someone from Alaska it hurts to shrink my state). I have to construct a larger infographic with supporting data and it is more conducive with a smaller, less accurate Alaska

Comment: @mkennedy Do you know of anyway to do it in qgis?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want? IMO this should be possible in QGIS with on-the-fly reprojection, scale, and inset maps in the print composer. You should not actually change the geometry.

Comment: @RichardLaw Right now I have two layers on top of each other, both chloropleth layers on the United States. I was thinking if I duplicated both layers and deleted everything out of the attribute table except for AK, then I would have an isolated layer with AK that I could move however I wanted in the print composer and then do the same thing for Hawaii. But I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it or even how exactly to go about altering the attribute tables like that

Answer (score 1):

You should create a composer with three map frames in it. Then you can change the scale of each map frame to whatever you want. It would be nice to put a scalebar or scale numbers in each, so that folks are aware that you're distorting things.